# Java EE 404 Error on XHTML but Not HTML

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm learning Java EE through a simple "Hello World" application, and when I run the program using `index.html` it works well. However, when I run the same program with `index.xhtml`, it throws a 404 Error saying "The requested resource is not available."

My folder structure is as follows:

[image]

When I run the program using `index.html`, I use the following URL: http://localhost:8081/index.html, and the page shows up with Hello World. And when I run using `index.xhtml`, I tried both: http://localhost:8081/example2/index.xhtml and http://localhost:8081/index.xhtml. Both give a 404 Error.

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I've also tried multiple browsers (Chrome and Firefox). Any ideas why I'm getting a 404 on XHTML but not HTML?

Comment: Show us all the web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple. When I checked the Tomcat logs, there was a ClassNotFoundException because Tomcat does not come with the [jsf-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.2.13) and [jsf-impl](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.13) jars. I created a new directory in WEB-INF called lib and put the 2 jars there. Yes, you need *both* jars. Now the XHTML file is found and the 404 goes away.

Answer (score 1):

You can config the home page in the web.xml with the code below:

```
<display-name>NameOfProject</display-name>

   <!-- Configuration of your home page  -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

So you can use both: 
http://localhost:8081/NameOfProject/   or
http://localhost:8081/NameOfProject/index.xhtml

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, unfortunately. Same thing still happens as described originally.

Comment: At the image it seems that you put your pages in the wrong place (WEB-INF). Move your pages to root of Web folder.

Comment: IntelliJ -- this is how the project was configured through the project wizard. Also, why would your suggestion solve the XHTML problem when everything works fine as is for HTML?

Comment: Notes: in the web.xml tag <welcome-file-list> the first file it find (note that all of them has the same name) it will be shown, so try remove one of them when you test.

Comment: Basic thing to Verify:
- import the library of JSF implemantation (like: Mojarra JavaServer Faces);
- you have to put this .jar in the web/lib folder;
- Config the web.xml e faces-config.xml .

Comment: Sorry, you have to put the JSF .jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder